# rotate canvas with setRotate(float degrees, float px, float py)? arround a pivot...Its not working right for me

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, accelerometer, sensors

When I am applying this for rotating canvas from a pivot point it is not working properly. It doesn't look like it's rotating point is unchanged. I have also applied this using matrix but at that time is not working as good i am finding rotating by canvas. I want to rotate a bitmap and i have some other images as well on UI. I am rotating canvas just before drawing the bitmap which i need to be rotating.

```
@Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{ 
    /* * draw the background */ 
    canvas.drawBitmap(mWood, 0, 0, null); 
    /* * compute the new position of our object, based on accelerometer  */ 
    final ParticleSystem particleSystem = mParticleSystem; 
    final long now = mSensorTimeStamp + (System.nanoTime() - mCpuTimeStamp); 
    final float sx = mSensorX; 
    final float sy = mSensorY; 
    particleSystem.update(sx, sy, now); 
    final Bitmap bitmap = mBitmap; 
    final Bitmap bitmapOvel = mBitmapOvel; 

    Paint p = new Paint(); 
    p.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
    p.setColor(Color.GREEN); 
    canvas.drawBitmap(mWoodDial, 10, centerY - centerX + 20, null); 
    p.setColor(Color.RED); 
    p.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE); 
    if (height <= 320) 
    {   
        p.setTextSize(14f); 
    } 
    else if (height <= 480) 
    { 
        p.setTextSize(18f); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        p.setTextSize(26f); 
    }
    String ss = Html.fromHtml(xx + "&#176 && " + yy + "&#176") .toString(); 
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmapOvelAlter, centerX + xx * 1.7f - 15f, centerY + 6f - yy, null); 
    canvas.rotate(xx, centerX, centerY); 
    p.setAntiAlias(true); 
    p.setFilterBitmap(true); 
    p.setDither(true); 
    canvas.save(); 
    canvas.drawBitmap(mWoodDial1, 10, centerY - centerX + 20, p); 
    canvas.restore(); 
    System.out.println("xx:" + xx + "::.. yy:" + yy); 
    // and make sure to redraw asap
    invalidate(); 
}
```

Comment: You are not going about this the right way.  Don't call invalidate in onDraw.  If you need to be constantly updating something then you should have a timer that ticks and calls invalidate on your view.  Even better, use a Surface view and handle the drawing loop yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the canvas.save() to before the canvas.rotate(). Otherwise you don't put the canvas back to the state it was given to you in.

Comment: after doing as u mentioned making no change in op.still having the same problem.

Comment: i am showing u the output i am getting please see the [link part 1](https://twitter.com/B_manmohan/status/254103298137784320/photo/1) and other [link part 2](https://twitter.com/B_manmohan/status/254103367519981568/photo/1)

Comment: So it is pivoting around a point, just not quite the correct point? If so, it's probably just that centerX and centerY aren't correct.

Comment: if something is rotating with a pivot point then that point will unchanged during movement.here if it is rotating using pivot then it must look a particular rotation.i am rotating using centerX and centerY .may b problem is here on pivot point but i am not able to found please suggest if you think any suggestion.if i write a point(120,160) then after not coming a ri8 soln.

Comment: by changing using hit n trial i have found approx solution.thanks